# Что значит ЧМО

Tags: аббревиатуры

Когда я впервые услышал слово "ЧМО", мне сказали, что это Человек, Мешающий Обществу. Так ли это ?

Answer (score 1):

И это тоже. Всё зависит от вашей фантазии.

Есть, правда, версия, что ЧМО - части материального обеспечения, военослужащие которых якобы носили во времена Великой Отечественной повязку с такой аббревиатурой - и пользовадлись дружным неуважением (зачастую - совершенно незаслуженным) со стороны представителей боевых частей.

Может оно и так, только вряд ли бы стало это словечко столь популярным, не будь в нем столь характерного "чмокающего" призвука нечаянно раздавленной коровьей лепешки.

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю происхождения этого слова, но для себя решила, что оно образовалось от "чума", "чумовой". Ругали ведь так людей неадекватных, да и сейчас бывает...

Comment: Выпадение У крайне сомнительно.